# Memory efficient variable types in Python

Tags: python

I am completely new in python and I have two questions about memory.

First:

Can I store exactly 2 bits per variable or with less memory than int?
My program works only with values 0, 1, 2, 3 and I would like to save memory.

```
getsizeof(1)   //12 bytes
getsizeof('A') //22 bytes, but I expected 2 bytes as char :(
```

Due to 2 bits, I need 12 or 22 bytes for each variable. Is possible solve this problem in pyhton?

Second similar problem:

I try to implement tree data structure, where each node have 4 children in correct order.
For example ideal like dict:

```
node = {1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None}
getsizeof(node) //57 bytes
```

or in array:

```
node = [None, None, None, None]
getsizeof(node) //52 bytes, where getsizeof([]) = 36 bytes
```

In fact, each node will contain 36 bytes uselessly. It is ~3.35Gb with 1 000 000 000 nodes. Is there any way to save memory?

Comment: Consider either a [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray) or use numpy

Comment: Do you plan on using tens or hundreds of GB of RAM for this program?

Comment: Python is in many ways not good for efficiency. If you are trying to create something very high performance your best option is to have it delegate to C, as numpy and pandas do.

Comment: TigerhawkT3: yes I do, at least tens GB and 3 GB can be critical.

Comment: dawg: how? I try to similar evaluation with getsizeof function on bytearays but it is still tens of bytes.

Comment: what is a `child` of a node in the second question?  Is it just an int, or another node?  also, are the number of nodes variable?

Comment: Note that Python does not have a specific 'char' data type; `'A'` and `"A"` both represent the same string of length 1.

Comment: Probably it is not possible in python. So I decide to store more values in one variable and try to some hard code optimizations. And with second problem I have to accept size of pointers because I realize that C won't be help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second problem is matter of pointers, delegate to C or another language is not solution because pointer will always take 8 or 4 bytes (depends on architecture). In addition, I assume to use 64b python for work with tens of GB so almost every variable type will be ~2 times greater.

For example:

```
node = [None, None, None, None]
node = [[[None, None, None, None], None, None, None], None, None, None]
```

Each "None" is possible reference to another node (pointer), so it is not possible to do optimization in this way. If you are sure that count of leaf will be e.g. less then ~65K, then you can decrease (~4 times) and modify size of pointer on 64b architecture for your needs.

Problem of first problem is similar (pointer will always take necessary space) and solution is use bit arrays or use bit operations and try to store more values in one variable. But if it is necessary to store exactly e.g 2 bytes values in some structure and then e.g. in array, it won't be memory-efficient in python.